# How to build Dynamic MongoDB Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 2 collections MongoDB. Keyword and PersonalInfo. I am receiving an array from client side like this:

```
[
 {fieldName : 'Keyword',operator: '===',value: 'soccer'},
 {fieldName : 'Keyword',operator: 'endsWith',value: 'cer'},
 {fieldName : 'Name',operator: 'startsWith',value: 'mik'}
]
```

I am using NodeJs where i need to build MongoDB query dynamically.
I have tried like this.

```
 let q = {};
  q["$and"] = [];

  let data = req.body;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // I tried without consideration of "operator" first but couldn't succeed. 

    let val = new RegExp(data[i].value);
    if (data[i].fieldName === "Keyword") {
      q["$and"].push({ Keyword: { $regex: val, $options: "-i" } });
    } else if (data[i].fieldName === "Name") {
      q["$and"].push({ Name: { $regex: val, $options: "-i" } }); //Since this field is from another collection, so instead of Name i want to push it as "$$name" so i could be able to use it in aggregates. 


    } 
  }
```

I was expecting to see an output like this.

```
{$and: 
[
 {Keyword: {$regex: 'search val', $options: "-i"}},
 {Name: {$regex: 'search val', $options: "-i"}},
]
}
```

But what i got is:

```
{$and: 
 [
 {Keyword: [Object]},
 {Name: [Object]},
]
}
```

How can i build the above query and implement this in aggregate like;

```
await Keyword.aggregate([
 {
  $lookup: {
    from: "PersonalInfo",
    let: { name: "$Name" },
    pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: q } }],
    as: "searchRecords"
  }
}
 ])
```

Here is my full code altogether.

```
let q = {};
  let results;
  let data = req.body;
  let and_conds = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let val = new RegExp(data[i].value);
    let field_name = data[i].fieldName;
    and_conds.push({ [field_name]: { $regex: val, $options: "-i" } });
  }
  q["$and"] = and_conds;

let records = await KeyInfo.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
        from: "PersonalInfo",
        let: { name: "$name" },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: q } }],
        as: "searchRecords"
      }
    }
   ]);
```

Thanks for your time and appreciate your help.

Comment: I think your query is correct but you are not printing it in right manner use `console.log(JSON.stringify(query, null, 2))` and check if your query is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, i'm not sure how you got your "output" (assuming you printed it) but its just showing you whats inside your object which is another object as expected.

The full code would look like this: (cleared it a little for read-ability only)

```
  let q = {};

  let data = req.body;
  let and_conds = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let val = new RegExp(data[i].value);
    let field_name = data[i].fieldName;
    and_conds.push({[field_name]: { $regex: val, $options: "-i" }})
  } 
  q["$and"] = and_conds;
```

- i'm not sure what you meant with the `$$name` comment as your only using these conditions after the lookup in the match phase but if all you have to do is change the `field_name` value from `"Name"` to `"$$name"`.

EDIT:

use this instead of the syntax above:

```
    let val = new RegExp(data[i].value, "i");
    and_conds.push({[field_name]: val)`
```

also you didnt change ur `fieldName` to be `"$$name"` you should do that too.

Comment: When i am running this query in my aggregates, i am getting this error:     MongoError: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $regex: /soccer/, $options: "-i" }.

Comment: post ur full pipeline please, this stage is not throwing this kind of error.

Comment: You're using it within an $expr, and $regex is not a valid expression read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions) what is valid, i'm gonna edit my answer with a valid expression using a regex synonym.